# Asp.net ChangePassword control doesnt change the password

Tags: webforms

I have tried almost every setting I could find but cant get to change the password.

```
<asp:ChangePassword ID="ChangePassword1" runat="server"
        ChangePasswordButtonStyle-CssClass="btnClass"
        CancelButtonStyle-CssClass="btnClass"
        BorderStyle="Solid"
        BorderWidth="1"
        MembershipProvider="MyMembership"
        DisplayUserName="true">
<CancelButtonStyle CssClass="btnClass"></CancelButtonStyle>

<ChangePasswordButtonStyle CssClass="btnClass"></ChangePasswordButtonStyle>
    </asp:ChangePassword>
```

I have the following setting for web.config

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Metamorphism;User id=sa;password=chandan;"/>
    <add name="MetamorphismConnectionString" connectionString="Data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Metamorphism;User id=sa;password=chandan;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <profile defaultProvider="MyProfile">
      <providers>
        <add name="MyProfile" type="System.Web.Providers.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="MyMembership">
      <providers>
        <add name="MyMembership" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" minRequiredPasswordLength="3"
 minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" enablePasswordReset="true" applicationName="Friendisc"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

All I get is the following error Password incorrect or New Password invalid. New Password length minimum: 3. Non-alphanumeric characters required: 0
But the password doesn't change at all

Comment: My apologies its changing password for some accounts and not for some. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was entering the wrong password and it wasn't working for some accounts